# onChange on dropdown is not working with form control

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular10

I've a problem with my dropdown. I have several values inside and like to use the selected one. This is my code, which is currently not working. The `FormControll` is always empty:

**app.component.html**

```
  <custom-dropdown [formControl]="majorAreaCtrl" (onChange)="onChange()" [label]="'EXPERTS.MAJOR_AREAS'|translate">
    <custom-dropdown-item *ngFor="let area of areas" [value]="area.key">
      {{ area }}
    </custom-dropdown-item>
  </custom-dropdown>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class ExpertsComponent implements OnInit {

  readonly majorAreas = MajorArea
  readonly areas = Object.values(this.majorAreas)
  readonly majorAreaCtrl = new FormControl()

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.majorAreas, this.allExperts)
  }

  onChange() {
    console.log(this.majorAreaCtrl.value)
  }
}
```

Do anyone see my mistake? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: i believe the value changes on next tick, so theoretically:
`setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.majorAreaCtrl.value); }, 0);` 
would work

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the `onChange` listener (the `[formControl]` binding handles that).
*However*, this requires that your `custom-dropdown` component implements the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface.

If that's the case, you should be able to respond to changes by subscribing to the `this.majorAreaCtrl.valueChanges` Observable (for instance).
Here's [a small example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-43wja3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), albeit without your custom component.

If your component doesn't implement `ControlValueAccessor`, I (and many others here) would be happy to help you implement it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it's not working as it should. When I log the `this.majorAreaCtrl.valuesChanges` I got nothing in my console. Or I mean not more than `EventEmitter_ {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}`

Comment: `this.majorAreaCtrl.valueChanges` is actually an Observable, so in order to react to changes to it, you will need to subscribe to it (at some point). As a quick test to see if it's working, try `this.majorAreaCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)`. That will log every time the Observable "emits" a value.